# Website not found -> 404 on each page including admin

Tags: magento-1.9, 404, index.php

I have just cloned a Magento website to my local environment and the website showing 404, regardless what page I visit even the admin panel is 404.

I am using Magento 1.9.3.8 and running it on MAMP 5.0.1

I have tried to visit the website with localhost/mywebsite/index.php, without it but still the same problem.

However, it finds the files when I visit localhost/mywebsite/LICENSE.TXT

The .htaccess file is included in the root directory

I have changed the web/unsecure/baseurl and web/secure/base_url and also the app/etc/local.xml with correct paths and db values.

Hope I was clear enough.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Check if .htaccess file is there in your root directory or not? If not there then download any default .htaccess for magento1 and place it under root and test again.